# How to prove monotonicity of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, probability

In probability, we often need to deal with dyadic rational numbers and floor functions.

Fix a  positive real number,

Define a sequence $a_n = \min(n, 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^nx\rfloor)$ , how to prove this sequence **increasingly** converge to $x$?

in the $\min$ expression, $n$ is of course increasing.

I am trying to compute quotient of the floor function part between
$a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$. Then $ a_{n+1}/a_n = \frac{\lfloor 2^{n+1} x\rfloor}{2\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor}$. How to proceed? Is my idea most efficient one?

This is a sequence used in Rosenthal's probability book. He used this to construct a sequence of simple functions converging to a positive random variable.

What's the general strategy for treating this kind of numerical question?

Comment: How is the "probability" tag relevant?

Comment: @jdods sorry, just added source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that $\frac{\lfloor 2^{n+1}x\rfloor}{2\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor} \geq 1$. for all $n$ and a fixed $x$. Let $u = 2^n x$, then the statement is equivalent to $\lfloor 2a\rfloor \geq 2\lfloor a\rfloor$. We divide this into two cases depending on $\{a\} = a - \lfloor a\rfloor$:

- If $0 \leq \{a\} < \frac{1}{2}$, then $\lfloor 2a \rfloor = \lfloor 2(\lfloor a\rfloor + \{a\})\rfloor = 2\lfloor a\rfloor + \lfloor\underbrace{2\{a\}}_{< 1}\rfloor = 2\lfloor a\rfloor$.
- If $\frac{1}{2} \leq \{a\} < 1$, then the underlined expression is between $1$ and $2$, and hence $\lfloor 2a\rfloor = 2\lfloor a\rfloor + 1$.

We see that in both cases, the statement holds.

Hope this helps!

Here is a picture, the red segments being $y = \lfloor 2x\rfloor$ and blue segments being $y = 2\lfloor x\rfloor$. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The expression $b_n(x) \equiv 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^nx\rfloor$ is just the approximation to $x$ using $n$ binary digits in the fractional part of the approximation, so it increases with $n$ for fixed $x$.

So $\min(n,b_n(x))$ caps $b_n$ at $n$, which produces an increasing sequence since $b_n(x)$ is increasing. In fact, once $n > \lceil x \rceil$, it must be true that $\min (n, b_n(x)) = b_n(x)$.

Comment: You meant if we write  $x$ in dyadic form? I am only familiar with $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: It's the same number no matter how you choose to write it. For example $\frac 12$ can be written as $0.5_{10}$ or as $0.1_{2}$ or as $0.1111\cdots_{3}$ etc.